# jquery mobile listview space between items / how to remove listview border

Tags: html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I want to put a space between listitems of a listview in jquery mobile. To do this i put a margin to each list item. So far this works fine but there is a border on the left and right side of the listview which one can especially see in the gaps. For example i have this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2BhAd/3/ . 
I tried to solve the problem by setting the border of the listview to none but that does not work.
CSS:

```
.listitem {
   margin-top: 10px !important;
}
#list {
   border:none !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
   <li class="listitem"><a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
        <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: If you dont want the corners in adition to the correct answer below add this css code ---- .ui-corner-all {
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.listitem {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
#list{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
#list .ui-li {
    border: none;
}
```

This removes the borders from the list and individual items. It also removes the shadowing effect on the list.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/2BhAd/4/)**